# How to pivot this set of data correctly?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have an excel sheet like this:

```
|  Time   |  Network1  |  Network2  |  ...  |  Networkn  |
|---------|------------|------------|-------|------------|
|  00:00  |  23.424    |   12323    |  ...  |  412       |
|  00:05  |  3112      |   1322     |  ...  |  123       |
|  ...    |  ...       |   ...      |  ...  |  ...       |
|  23:55  |  1321      |   4124     |  ...  |  214       |
```

where the values of each network column is the traffic for that specific time.

I want to re-arrange the data so it will create something like this:

```
|  Time   |  Networks  |  Traffic   |
|---------|------------|------------|
|  00:00  |  Network1  |   23.424   |  
|  00:00  |  Network2  |   12323    |  
|  ...    |  ...       |   ...      |  
|  23:55  |  Networkn  |   214      |
```

It's like groupby(Time, network_names, traffic_of_each_network_per_Time).

I was playing with the PivotTable Fields but didn't figure it out yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: looks like you need to `unpivot` the data, you can do this with `Power Pivot`

Comment: Hey @PeterH thanks for commenting. I am afraid I can't get access to the Power Pivot Add-In to check how I can do this. can you think of any other work-arounds?

Comment: use Power Query to [unpivot](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098) your data. Since Excel 2016 it's fully integrated in Excel (known as [Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/get-transform-in-excel-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de))